# Cp default timeout limit

Tags: networking, cp, cygwin, timeout

I have a script that creates and copies a file to multiple machine on a network.

Sometimes a machine or two may be down, which in turn causes the cp to take a really long time to timeout.

My questions are:

1. what is the default timeout of this?
2. Can one actually override this in order to lower it?

Comment: What's doing the actual network transfer?

Comment: Remote file systems? What type, which configuration? internets?

Comment: It's a topology of some Windows machines. The command is ran through cygwin.

The topology itself almost always contains a number of machines on a LAN subnet and a most time a single machine that acts as a DMZ.

Firewalling and network traffic allows them to communicate with one another.

One machine runs the script which creates the new file and then it gets copied to the other ones.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Windows question and not a Linux/Unix question

Answer (score 3):

`cp`, by itself, does not impose a timeout. If one of the filesystems blocks or is slow, the command could keep running for an arbitrarily long time.

You could try forcing the command to stop after a while using `timeout`: for example `timeout 30 cp <source> <destination>` would start `cp` and then kill it if it has not completed after 30 seconds. Depending on why, in your use case, the copy takes an abnormally long time, this may or may not do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

rsync has a timeout options

```
        --timeout=SECONDS       set I/O timeout in seconds
```

you can use it as an enhanced cp.